# Django - Making TabulerInline's classes to collapse

Tags: django, django-admin

I just want to hide/show the inlines in admin interface like providing classes': ['collapse']}). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do this the official way, but my first thought is to override admin html template and put there some short jQuery script like:

```
    $('inline-panel-selector').click(function() {$(this).toggle(200);});
```

EDIT:

As for which template should be overriden, take a look here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model

-- I think it should be `change_form.html` and it could look roughly like this:

```
{% extends "change_form.html" %}
{% block footer %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $('inline-panel-selector').click(function() {$(this).toggle(200);});
        });
    </script>
 {% endblock %}
```

Note that I'm not sure if `$` symbol is available, something tells me that Django doesn't expose it, using something like `django.jQuery` instead.

Comment: Can you please provide the file name where this line can added?